# Under what conditions is posterior expected 0-1 loss minimized by the MAP estimate?

Tags: bayesian, estimation, decision-theory

Suppose we observe data $x$ from a distribution with density function $p_\theta(x)$ with unknown $\theta$, we have a prior density $\pi(\theta)$, and we want to minimize the following loss function:
$$L_\epsilon(\theta, \hat{\theta}) = \begin{cases}
0 & \text{if } |\theta-\hat{\theta}| < \epsilon \\
1 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
Consider the posterior expectation of this loss function,
$$E[L_\epsilon(\Theta, \hat{\theta})|x] = \frac{\int L_\epsilon(\theta, \hat{\theta}) p_\theta(x) \pi(\theta) d\theta}{\int p_\theta(x) \pi(\theta) d\theta}$$
Let $\hat{\theta}_\epsilon$ be the estimate that minimizes this loss function,
$$\hat{\theta}_\epsilon=\underset{\hat{\theta}}{\text{argmin}}\, E[L_\epsilon(\theta, \hat{\theta})|x]$$
It is often claimed that this estimate is, in the limit of small $\epsilon$, equal to the maximum a posteriori (MAP) estimate:
$$\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0} \hat{\theta}_\epsilon = \underset{\theta}{\text{argmax}}\, p_\theta(x) \pi(\theta) = \hat{\theta}_{\text{MAP}}$$
An example of this claim is in [section 4.1.2 of The Bayesian Choice](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=6oQ4s8Pq9pYC&oi=fnd&pg=PR7&dq=map+estimate+0+1+loss+bayesian+decision+theory&ots=qCP_nHVgPd&sig=ZaOM0_iMAOvrMJDlHemGnwuEC70#v=onepage&q=MAP%20estimator&f=false). And I believe it, at least for discrete $\theta$ and for continuous $\theta$ where the density functions $p_\theta(x) \pi(\theta)$ are smooth in some sense. What I can't find is, exactly what sense of smoothness do we need? What are the general conditions under which this holds? And when does it fail, and why?

I get the intuition behind it (explained very well in [these lecture notes](http://www.lx.it.pt/~mtf/learning/Bayes_lecture_notes.pdf), by the way). What I'm looking for are the mathematical conditions.